# UINavigationController inside UIViewController that is inside a UINavigationConroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Navigation application that has a view controller in it.. I am now trying to load another NavigationController into that ViewController however I am experiencing problems..

I am trying to do it programmatically because I am not sure how to do it in InterfaceBuilder however the new navigation controller displayes weird.. like it thinks there is a infobar above it.. so has a white gap..

As you can see here.

[image]

This is all I am doing to get this ^ current look....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UINavigationController *newNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:newNav.view];

    newNav.navigationItem.title=@"Navigation Controller Example";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like inception here, why do you want a navigation controller within a navigation controller? I suspect there's a better way to do what you're trying to do, normally we use the one navigation controller to push subsequent views, then if you need a separate navigation set you could use a modal segue to another one...

Comment: well when the user gets to this view in the main navigaitonstack I would like the user to be able to swipe between views left and right (which I am going to change the animation to work like this for the second navigation controller)... its just a way i was told to do it in another question and is the reason why I am heading down this track..

Comment: Oh, if you're letting them swipe between sibling views you should manage them with a page control. Nav controllers are meant for top-down hierarchy, where each view added is a child of the one before it. Apple might reject your app if you use a nav controller the way you're planning to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say,you just have an Navi-based App, so if you want to add another NavigationController in your application ,you should hide the new NavigationController's bar .Following is the code.

```
[newNav setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: ahh.. this even made the small white bar across the top disappear.. thanks for the help.

Comment: I just turned animated off, and it will not show the detail view that appears inside the navigationcontroller..... but if I have animated as YES it shows up fine...